# How do I removed Conditional Formatting after its been applied?

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have a worksheet change macro that highlights the first 8 cells in a row if the last cell contains the word "Cancelled".  This works fine.  However the word cancelled is in a drop down menu and if you accidently select it the macro kicks in.  If you change to another word in the same cell, I would like it to remove the condition and go back to normal. Can someone help me out with this.  Im sure it is something simple that I'm missing.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
   
    If UsedRange.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        If Trim(Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column)) <> "" And _
            UCase(Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column)) = "CANCELLED" Then
            
            Range(Cells(Target.Row, 1), Cells(Target.Row, 8)).Interior.Color = vbRed
            Range(Cells(Target.Row, 1), Cells(Target.Row, 8)).Font.Color = vbWhite
       
        ElseIf Trim(Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column)) <> "" And _
            UCase(Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column)) <> "CANCELLED" Then
         
                
            Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
            
        
        
        End If
    End If
ErrHandler:
    '
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Do note that you're not actually applying conditional formatting in the true sense of the term. You're directly changing the format of the cells in question.

Comment: Is there a way to remove that change in formatting without removing all formatting on the entire sheet.  I feel like thats what would happen if I went down that route.

Comment: Sure, for example setting the `Interior.Color` to `vbWhite` and maybe changing the font color to black for example.

Comment: I had this earlier and it works for the row that was changed  but when I fill in the rest of the form, it changes that as well.

Comment: The Drop down menu that has the word cancelled also has three other phrases and I tried to have it revert the change if it contained those phrases as well.

Comment: I updated my post with a picture.  I dont want any of this to affect anything inside the black area.  Keep in mind that there are more than one of these setups in a single sheet.

Comment: Is there a reason this must be done in VBA and not with actual conditional formatting?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad the reason I cant use traditional conditional formatting is the way I add a new order to the spreadsheet is by copying the formatting from a different hidden sheet and pasting it under the last order that was placed.  The conditional formatting I have set up on the hidden sheet doesnt carry over to the new sheet.  Either by design or I am not doing it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't "apply" and "remove". You "apply" in both cases, just that you apply different colours.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const TriggerClm    As Long = 8         ' change to suit
    Dim TriggerRng      As Range
    Dim TargetRng       As Range
    Dim IntCol          As Long
    
    ' Here the first row is 2, presuming row 1 contains captions
    Set TriggerRng = Range(Cells(2, TriggerClm), Cells(Rows.Count, TriggerClm).End(xlUp))
    
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, TriggerRng) Is Nothing Then
        With Target
            Set TargetRng = Range(Cells(.Row, TriggerClm - 7), Cells(.Row, TriggerClm))
            If StrComp(CStr(.Value), "cancelled", vbTextCompare) Then
                TargetRng.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
                TargetRng.Font.Color = vbBlack
            Else
                TargetRng.Interior.Color = vbRed
                TargetRng.Font.Color = vbWhite
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Observe that I reasoned that a change can only be triggered if a cell in the 8th column is changed because only that cell is either "Cancelled" or not. My code's logic deviates from yours in this respect.

Comment: I never thought of changing the target of the worksheet change to just that column.  This is sad since I do this exact thing in another marco for a different workbook.  This does effect the row for all the drop down menus which is what I was trying to avoid but I will just change those around so none of them are in the target row.  Thanks for the help.